# Cron in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

My objective is to execute a custom class/method (e.g. send data to a backend system) every X minutes. Seems cron is the way to go. Though, I'm new to cron in Magento 2.

What I see so far is I should create a etc\crontab.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
<job name="mymodule_orders_job" instance="My\Module\Model\Observer" >
<schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
</job>
</group>
</config>
```

and "Observer" does the work. Seems simple enough.

What I'm confused on is, how does this get into cron (crontab)?  Also, I see there's a cron_schedule table...not sure what that's used for.

Finally, I want the flexibility to 1) enabled/disabled the job in a custom Admin config and 2) set the interval on the same custom Admin.

I suspect for the custom Admin it would create the etc\crontab.xml and set parms accordingly? Also, since this is a packaged module need the module to be able set things up inclusively

Comment: Regarding cron job, look at how to [make it run](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93626/697). This job will process crontab.xml. For other issues, create separate questions so that each question has one canonical answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex!  Starting to get a handle on this.  So I now understand that magento needs to be a "job"  `echo "* * * * * php ${project_root}/bin/magento cron:run &" | crontab -u www-data -` and for my module add etc\crontab.xml.  As you suggest I'll create another question for my other questions

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/asulpunto-cronedit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need setup not only a cron job execution schedule in a Magento 2 extension, but also setup a [generic cron job execution schedule](https://mage2.pro/t/32) in an operating system.

The operating system will run Magento 2 by the schedule, and Magento 2 will check it's internal schedule and run the appropriate extensions jobs.

The generic operating system schedule should run Magento 2 more frequent then any of internal Magento 2 schedules. I recommend run Magento 2 every 5-10-15 minutes, depends on your server performance.