# Magento 2 core files

Tags: magento2, core

What folders/files are now considered core for Magento 2? As in "Don't edit these files since they can be overwritten in an update"
I need to scan a site for core overrides and I'm looking for the folders to compare against fresh install.

Comment: you have ask the question? :). I am not believe that. But anyhow it is good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Assume "core" by default

When you initially download Magento through composer, it *creates* all of those folders and files.  This means that *all* of those can be updated by Magento.

The only safe files to modify are:

- `composer.json` and `composer.lock`
- anything  in the `app` folder
- as well as any files you've manually created in the root folder (such as `nginx.conf` or `.gitignore`)

(These also happen to be the same files you should commit, except for `app/etc/env.php`)

Trying to compare to a fresh install likely won't work:  Consider the `vendor` folder.  It has stuff from Magento itself, but if you ever add a module from a 3rd party, it also goes in the `vendor` folder.  (In fact, I recommend adding your custom site changes this way as well).

However, your problem (I believe) is solved if you only let people commit certain files (as I've listed above).  This way, you know that they aren't overriding core files.  See [GIT and deployment strategies](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93676/47655) (I recommend
Vladimir's answer)

Comment: I thought about using a git based strategy for this too. It’s not for a project, it’s for an script I’m building to see if a site’s core is edited. I agree it’s not very precise to just pick some dirs and leave the rest out.

Comment: If you are determined to do a script this way, there's no easy rule to apply, because its hard to tell which changes actually change the functionality.  Regardless, I recommend that you ignore any extra files (except for files in any `etc` folder), and ignore modifications to the files listed above.

Answer (score 4):

Usualy `/vendor/` files and `/lib/` files. you can make extends / override the files if you use the needed path for the file you want to change, ex:
if you want to edit `menu.js` file from `/lib/web/mage` you would have to do an extend of it and declare it in `requirejs-config.js` of your theme or ( **NOT RECOMANDED** ) copy the file in `Your_Theme/web/mage/` and it will override it.